# Animated border CSS not working on Firefox: CSS is a combination of tailwind and custom CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

The animated border is working perfectly on Chrome, but on Firefox the border is not even showing, let alone the animation working. Need help with this

CSS file:

```
@import "keyframes.css";

@layer components {
  .animated-chevron {
    @apply relative;
    &:before {
      @apply content-[''] absolute w-0 h-[0.18rem] top-[41%] right-[-0.05rem] mr-[0.5rem] bg-current rounded group-hover:w-[0.55rem] group-hover:md:w-[0.7rem] transition-all duration-medium;
    }
  }
}

@layer utilities {
  .splash {
    @apply relative overflow-hidden;
    &:after {
      @apply content-[''] absolute block bg-white w-0 h-0 hover:w-[100%] hover:h-[100%] top-1/2 left-1/2 opacity-[0.15] rounded-full -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 transition-all duration-long;
    }
  }
  .animated-border {
    @apply relative;
    &:before,
    &:after {
      -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
      -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
      mask-composite: exclude;
      @apply content-[''] absolute inset-0 rounded-primary border-[1.5px] border-transparent filter contrast-[6] bg-current pointer-events-none transition-all duration-1000;
    }
    &:after {
      background: linear-gradient(var(--angle), var(--tw-gradient-stops)) border-box;
      @apply animate-[rotate_4s_linear_infinite] opacity-0 hover:opacity-100;
    }
  }
  .animated-border-static {
    @apply animated-border from-primary-light via-black via-[70%] to-gray-light after:opacity-100;
    &:before {
      all: unset;
    }
  }
}
```

JSX file:

```
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

const StatusCard = ({ className, title, subtitle, icon: Icon }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={twMerge(
        "group w-full flex flex-col place-items-center relative py-5 px-3 md:py-7 md:px-7 gap-1 animated-border-static revert",
        className
      )}
    >
      <div className="opacity-80 mb-3 transform scale-75 md:scale-100 rounded-2xl p-5 flex aspect-square rotate-45 md:mt-2 bg-gray-200">
        <Icon className="w-8 h-8 -rotate-45 fill-black" />
      </div>
      <span className="font-semibold text-sm md:text-base -mt-3 md:mt-2">{title}</span>
      <span className="font-medium text-sm md:text-base">{subtitle}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StatusCard;
```

Keyframes.css

```
@property --angle {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    --angle: 360deg;
  }
}
```

When I comment the :

```
:before {
all: unset;
}
```

the border starts showing up on Firefox, ofcourse but the animation still not working, but maybe Firefox has issue with suedo selectors

Answer (score 0):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property#browser_compatibility), Firefox does not support the `@property` at-rule at the time of writing. This means that `--angle` has no default value. Which means that the `linear-gradient()` value in the `background` declaration in the `.animated-border:after` rule would be invalid:

```css
.animated-border:after {
  background: linear-gradient(var(--angle), var(--tw-gradient-stops)) border-box;
}
```

To have at least the animated border display in Firefox, consider adding the default "inline":

```css
.animated-border:after {
  background: linear-gradient(var(--angle, 0deg), var(--tw-gradient-stops)) border-box;
}
```

```js
const Icon = () => "icon"

const StatusCard = ({ title, subtitle }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="group w-full flex flex-col place-items-center relative py-5 px-3 md:py-7 md:px-7 gap-1 animated-border-static revert"
    >
      <div className="opacity-80 mb-3 transform scale-75 md:scale-100 rounded-2xl p-5 flex aspect-square rotate-45 md:mt-2 bg-gray-200">
        <Icon className="w-8 h-8 -rotate-45 fill-black" />
      </div>
      <span className="font-semibold text-sm md:text-base -mt-3 md:mt-2">{title}</span>
      <span className="font-medium text-sm md:text-base">{subtitle}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<StatusCard title="Foo" subtitle="Bar"/>);

tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primary-light': 'red',
        'gray-light': 'lightgray',
      },
      borderRadius: {
        primary: '20px',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
@property --angle {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    --angle: 360deg;
  }
}

@layer utilities {
  .animated-border {
    @apply relative;
  }
  .animated-border:before,
  .animated-border:after {
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
    mask-composite: exclude;
    @apply content-[''] absolute inset-0 rounded-primary border-[1.5px] border-transparent filter contrast-[6] bg-current pointer-events-none transition-all duration-1000;
  }
  .animated-border:after {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--angle, 0deg), var(--tw-gradient-stops)) border-box;
    @apply animate-[rotate_4s_linear_infinite] opacity-0 hover:opacity-100;
  }
  .animated-border-static {
    @apply animated-border from-primary-light via-black via-[70%] to-gray-light after:opacity-100;
  }
  .animated-border-static:before {
    all: unset;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. By following your solution, the border does show up on firefox however, the animation is still not working.

Comment: As per the first sentence in my answer, "[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property#browser_compatibility), Firefox does not support the `@property` at-rule at the time of writing." So the animation would not work since it relies on `--angle` being animatable.

Comment: oh okay so I shall refactor the --angle then to make it compatible. Thanks, @Wongjn